# Setting TextView to right of vertical LinearLayout in android

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I tried to add a TextView to a vertical LinearLayout and align the text view to right of layout:

```
LinearLayout temprLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
            temprLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            theTemprature = new TextView(this);
            theTemprature.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            theTemprature.setTextSize(21);
            theTemprature.setTextColor(0xffffCC33);

            theUVText = new TextView(this);
            theUVText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            theUVText.setTextSize(21);
            theUVText.setTextColor(0xfff5b800);
            theUVText.setBackgroundColor(0xff423234);
            theUVText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP);

            theUVText.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Gravity.RIGHT));

            temprLayout.addView(theTemprature, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Gravity.RIGHT));
            temprLayout.addView(theUVText, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Gravity.RIGHT));
```

But the textview remains aligned to the left of layout

Answer (score 4):

Try setting up your LinearLayout to MATCH_PARENT width.

Comment: FILL_PARENT is deprecated by android-8, use MATCH_PARENT for android-8 and higher.

Comment: Interesting, for some reason I thought it was the other way around.  Thanks for the tip @Renaud

Comment: Gravity right can only go as far right as the containing layout goes.  If you want it to go all the way right, you have to make sure the LinearLayout fills that space -- hope that made sense!